# what is the order of mathematical calculations in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to calculate the output of this problem in python: 4+6/2 and it was 7 then i reversed them as 6+4/2 and answer was 8. now whats the difference, and why this occurs? what is divided first?

Comment: Those are different things in all programming languages that I've ever seen, and in math. Would you expect them to give the same answer if you did this with a pencil and paper?

Comment: See [Precedence of Python operations](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity)

Comment: Sounds like you expected `(4+6)/2` vs `(6+4)/2`, which are both 5

Answer (score 1):

Python uses PEMDAS, as do most languages. Division comes before addition, so it would be calculated as 4+(6/2)=4+3=7, and 6+(4/2)=8. This can be confirmed with any calculator.

PEMDAS is the standard order of operations:

P- Parentheses first

E- Exponents second

M/D- Multiplication or Division third (If there are multiple
multiplication or division signs in a row, then operate first to last)

A/S- Addition or Subtraction fourth (If there are multiple addition or
subtraction signs in a row, then operate first to last)

Comment: An explanation of what `PEMDAS` means would improve this answer greatly.

Comment: explanation added

Comment: thank you very much but i still have one more question:as you said, if we try to calculate this:4+6/2, python first will calculate the outcome of 6/2 then +4, why doesn't it first calculate this 4/2 then + 6?

Comment: Why would it calculate 4/2 and add 6? 4+6/2=7
4+(6/2)=4+3=7

Comment: I got it, I calculated it using a calculator and the answer was just as you said.THANK YOU VERY MUCH.